# Checkout and Success page

Tags: bigcartel

I've installed a 3rd party bigcartel theme, and was wondering what happened to the success and checkout page. I am unable to edit these pages, is this feature gone? Is there any way i can edit these pages?

Comment: can't help if there is no content in your question.

Comment: I am using the neat theme, with the 3rd party theme legend lite

Answer (score 0):

The ability to edit the Checkout and Success page is only available when you have PayPal Standard enabled as a checkout option - with Seamless Checkout (using Stripe or PayPal Express), those pages aren't editable.